# C# : Assign generic Multicast-Delegate to Action with different amount of parameters via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, types, delegates, action

So in my class are some delegates all being Action<...> fields. Example:

```
public Action<int> onDiceRolled;
public Action<Turn, Round> onTurnEnded;
```

and I want to assign an anonymous function to each of them using reflection.

```
    GetType().GetFields()
    .Where(field => field.FieldType.ToString().Contains("Action"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(field =>
    {
        Type type = field.FieldType; // e.g. Action<Turn, Round>
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return;

        Type[] para = type.GetGenericArguments(); // in example cases: {int} or {Turn, Round}
        MethodInfo debugMethod = (new Action(() => Console.WriteLine(field.Name + " was called."))).Method;
        field.SetValue(this, Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, debugMethod));
    });
```

Of course this does not work since the created delegate does not have any parameter while the parameters it needs are stored in para.
Unfortunately I cannot find any way to create a delegate by an array of types.

So basically I want to do

```
onDiceRolled += (i) => Console.WriteLine("onDiceRolled was called.");
```

for each action field in my class

Comment: `SetValue` is not an equivalent of `+=` which is `System.Delegate.Combine` for delegates.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Until now it does not matter if I set or add the delegate. First, the types must match because If they dont't, adding delegates will also not work. So the problem with the types remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the delegate you can use [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) to compile one:

```
GetType().GetFields()
   .Where(field => field.FieldType.ToString().Contains("Action"))
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(field =>
   {
       Type type = field.FieldType; // e.g. Action<Turn, Round>
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
           return;

       Type[] para = type.GetGenericArguments(); // in example cases: {int} or {Turn, Round}
       Expression<Action> x = () => Console.WriteLine(field.Name + " was called.");
       var action = Expression.Lambda(x.Body, para.Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p))).Compile();
       field.SetValue(this, action);
   });
```